# Safari private navigation session

Tags: mac, safari, macos

Is there any way to stay logged when pressing **open in new tabs** in safari private mode ?

For example if I'm logged to Facebook in **tab A**  an I use **Open in new tabs** then I will have to sign into Facebook again.

Comment: How is it going to know it's still you, without cookies? That's the entire idea of private browsing.

Comment: You can think of private as a black box that gets created and have no access to anything you previously done. Also the box gets deleted when the private window is closed. It's like browsing in a totally different browser.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox allows sharing sessions between tabs in private session. So technechly it's possible but the question can safari do that ?